# MongoDB 3.4 Document Validation match "exists" or "is in"

Tags: mongodb, validation, nosql

I'm new to MongoDB noSQL Database and new to Document Validation.

I want to specify for a collection that a field doesn't "exists" or its value is one between 0,1,2,3

I have tried in the following format:

```
db.createCollection("tickets", {

validator:{

    $or:[{status:{$exists:false}},{status:{$in:[NumberInt(0),NumberInt(1),NumberInt(2),NumberInt(3)]}}]
    }
})
```

MongoDB allows me to insert the object:

```
db.tickets.insert({
    status: NumberInt(8)
})
```

Both individually the $exists and $in operators works for me...
What i'm doing wrong?

I tried with this example:

```
db.dropDatabase()
use prova
db.createCollection("tickets", {

validator: {

    $or: [{data:{$exists: false}}, {data: {$type: "date"}}],
    $or: [{status:{$exists: false}}, {status: {$in: [NumberInt(0), NumberInt(1), NumberInt(2), NumberInt(3)]}}],

}
})

db.tickets.insert({})                                           //Must be correct
db.tickets.insert({data:"hello"})                               //Must be wrong 
db.tickets.insert({data:new Date()})                            //Must be correct
db.tickets.insert({status:NumberInt(5)})                        //Must be wrong
db.tickets.insert({status:NumberInt(3)})                        //Must be correct
db.tickets.insert({data:new Date(), status:NumberInt(2)})       //Must be correct
```

Response: ALL OK
...?

i have this output from db.getCollectionInfos():

```
 /* 1 */
 [
     {
         "name" : "tickets",
         "type" : "collection",
         "options" : {
            "validator" : {
                "$or" : [ 
                    {
                        "status" : {
                            "$exists" : false
                        }
                    }, 
                    {
                        "status" : {
                            "$in" : [ 
                                 0, 
                                 1, 
                                 2, 
                                 3
                             ]
                         }
                     }
                 ]
             }
    },
    "info" : {
        "readOnly" : false
    },
    "idIndex" : {
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "name" : "_id_",
        "ns" : "prova.tickets"
    }
}
```

]

Comment: The output  with the from db.getCollectionInfos()  doesnt match with the validator you defined above. where are validations for data ?

Comment: Can you just drop database and try db.createCollection("tickets", {

validator: {

    $or: [{status:{$exists: false}}, {status: {$in: [NumberInt(0), NumberInt(1), NumberInt(2), NumberInt(3)]}}],

}
}) and after that insert status:8 and insert and let me somefield:2 and let me know the response you get ?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me: add $and[] operator wrapping the lines of validator:

```
db.dropDatabase()
use prova
db.createCollection("tickets", {

validator: {

   $and:[
    {$or: [{data:{$exists: false}}, {data: {$type: "date"}}]},
    {$or: [{status:{$exists: false}}, {status: {$in: [NumberInt(0), NumberInt(1), NumberInt(2), NumberInt(3)]}}]}
        ]
 }
})

db.tickets.insert({})                                           //Must be correct
db.tickets.insert({data:"hello"})                               //Must be wrong 
db.tickets.insert({data:new Date()})                            //Must be correct
db.tickets.insert({status:NumberInt(5)})                        //Must be wrong
db.tickets.insert({status:NumberInt(3)})                        //Must be correct
db.tickets.insert({data:new Date(), status:NumberInt(2)})       //Must be correct
```

Result : OK, Schema Error, OK, Schema Error, OK, OK

Thanks!